# Rn42 Bluetooth Module does not respond

Tags: bluetooth, no-response

I want to send some commands to my RN42 Bluetooth Module over the serial port using hterm. But i does not respond. I can connect to the bluetooth modul and the status LED blinks right. 
I tried to send $$$ to change to command mode (modul should respond with cmd but does nothing) and 0x00 to disconnect.
Do you guys know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things that I have run into that you could try:

- Ensure that the baud rate of hterm is set to the default 115k
- Depending on the firmware version of the RN42 you may have to enter command mode within a one minute time frame. Try power cycling the module and sending the $$$ as soon as possible